# AWS Redshift ETL Process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm investigating redshift for our Data Warehouse, and I'm trying to think of how to architect a solution.

I have an instance of Amazon Kinesis Firehose as a delivery stream which writes to my Redshift database, and all that works fine.

Now my issue is how do I automate the creation of dimensions and fact tables.

Can I use a Lambda function in the delivery stream to write to the fact table and update the dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

The Data Transformation capability of AWS Lambda on an Amazon Kinesis Firehose is purely to modify or exclude streaming data. It cannot be used to create other tables.

If you wish to create dimension and fact tables, or otherwise perform ETL, you'll need to trigger it externally, such as having a **scheduled task** run SQL commands on your Amazon Redshift instance. This task would connect via JDBC/ODBC to run the commands.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? like how do I create a scheduled task?

Comment: You would have to create the code and the scheduled trigger yourself, either on your own computer or on an Amazon EC2 instance. It is not a feature of Kinesis. (It might be a feature of the upcoming Amazon Glue product.) Or, you could create a schedule in [Amazon CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) that calls an AWS Lambda function that you have written.

Comment: nah but why can't I put it I here? https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvtcpny4i01bxam/Screen%20Shot%202017-06-06%20at%2010.58.50%20am.png?dl=0

Comment: My understanding is that the Lambda function that is triggered by Kinesis Firehose can manipulate the incoming data and can choose to modify or drop records, but it outputs the data that is then stored in Redshift. It cannot be used to create/modify other tables -- it's just transforming the data stream that comes in.

Comment: so what you're suggesting is write a lambda function in node js/python that does the transformation and is triggered via cloud watch?

Comment: Yes. However, triggering an ETL job by schedule might not be the perfect option (eg often you want to do it after a load has finished).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145927/discussion-between-hades-and-john-rotenstein).